# Finding $h_{\max}$ in time $T$ , when a particle is thrown vertically up

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile

I want to find the exact value of $h_{\max}$ & $T$ .

$\Rightarrow$ For $h_{\max}$, lets say $T$ is constant. For a small instant , $a$ must be uniform , i.e. $$a=g\left(1+\frac{h}{R}\right)^{-2}$$ So , $$\frac{du}{dt}=g\left(1+\frac{h}{R}\right)^{-2}$$

Now , $$T\to h_{\max}$$ $$dt\to\frac{ T}{h_{\max}}dh$$ Hence , $$u=\int_{0}^{h_{\max}}g\left(1+\frac{h}{R}\right)^{-2}\frac{T}{h_{\max}}dh$$

So, From here we can find $h_{\max}$, But I'm not able to find $T$, help me with this.